# Activating the NEBS Compliance SFP on Juniper MX disabled due to Ambient Temperature Exceeded

Tags: juniper, sfp, juniper-mx

We have faced an issue on Juniper MX960 that some SFPs (10G Optics) were disabled due to ambient temperature exceeded. This was observed in the syslog messages on MX. However after the physical environment being ok , those SFPs were not coming up. Hence the corresponding 10G links were also down.

As per Juniper Documentation , the optics that have been disabled due to temperature can be reactivated through CLI. (https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/request-chassis-optics.html)

```
request chassis optics fpc-slot fpc-slot-number reactivate
```

But the above command activate only **NON-NEBS** compliance optics. In our case optics are **NEBS** compliance verified by shell interface on MPC.

Can someone please guide how to activate NEBS compiance optics that has been disabled by ambient temperature exceeded.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you did try to put the port admin DOWN, then UP. When putting them UP do you have any message in the log?

Comment: I'll take a look, though it might take me a couple of days.

Comment: @JFL.  The interface went down due to ambient temperature of optics exceeded.

Comment: Yes I know that, but still if the interface doesn't come back up when the temperature issue is solved, you can still try to put it down / up administratively then check the log.

Comment: @JordanHead. I have posted an answer. Please check if it is okay. Thanks.

Comment: @NABEELNASIR - If JFL's suggestion didn't work, this is probably the best way to do it for individual optics.  I think you can also reboot the FPC if it's the entire card.  I couldn't find a command to do what you were asking.  I'd go ahead and mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is based on my experience of the problem.

So in order to activate NEBS compliance optics that has been disabled by ambient temperature exceeded , we can simply take SFP out of line card's port  and then plug it back i.e. we have to re seat the SFP. Once re seated , the interface will come up automatically.